# Inject javascript into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, code-injection

I've got a weird question in that I need to inject some javascript into another javascript function. I am using a framework which is locked so I can not change the existing function.

What I've got is something like this

function doSomething(){
...
}

...***

I can manipulate the ***(above) however I can not change the doSomething function... Instead I need to somehow inject a few lines of code into the end of the doSomething code.

The reason I need to do this is that the custom framework calls doSomething() and this results in an ID being returned from the server that I need to extract. This ID is only referenced inside the doSomething function so I can not catch it unless I inject code to that function (unless I've missed something).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How is the function 'locked'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to wrap all JavaScript methods with a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919134/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-all-javascript-methods-with-a-function)

Answer (score 9):

Alias it.

```
var oldDoSomething = doSomething;
doSomething = function() {
  // Do what you need to do.
  return oldDoSomething.apply(oldDoSomething, arguments);
}
```

Comment: he needs access to a variable that is scoped to the original function

Comment: Bad answer. Requires case by case usage.

Answer (score 6):

Altering the function by working with the source code strings can be quite simple. To do it for a specific instance, try:

```
eval(doSomething.toString().replace(/}\s*$/, ' return id; $&'));
```

Now `doSomething` returns the ID. I'm not normally a fan of `eval`, but normal [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) techniques don't apply here, due to the requirement for accessing a local variable.

If `doSomething` already returns a value, try wrapping the body in a `try ... finally`:

```
eval(doSomething.toString()
    .replace(/^function *\w* *\([^)]*\) *{/, '$& try {')
    .replace(/}\s*$/, '} finally { window.someID = id; } $&')
);
```

To turn this into a function, we need to make the code [evaluate in global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4670805/90527). Originally, this answer made use of `with` to change the scope of the `eval`, but this doesn't currently work in browsers. Instead, `.call` is used to change the scope of `eval` to `window`.

```
(function () {
    var begin = /^function\s*\w*\s*\([^)]*\)\s*{/,
        end = /}\s*$/;

    function alter(func, replacer) {
        var newFunc = replacer(func.toString());
        eval.call(window, newFunc);
    }
    
    function insertCode(func, replacer, pattern) {
        alter(func, function (source) { 
            return source.replace(pattern, replacer);
        });
    };
    
    /* Note: explicit `window` to mark these as globals */
    window.before = function (func, code) {
        return insertCode(func, '$& ' + code, begin);
    };
    
    window.after = function (func, code) {
        return insertCode(func, code + ' $&', end);
    };
    
    window.around = function (func, pre, post) {
        /* Can't simply call `before` and `after`, as a partial code insertion may produce a syntax error. */
        alter(func, function(source) {
            return source
                .replace(begin, '$& ' + pre)
                .replace(end, post + ' $&');
        });
    };
})();
...
after(doSomething, 'return id;');
/* or */
around(doSomething, 'try {', '} finally { window.someID = id; }');
```

If you want to rewrite methods and anonymous functions bound to variables, change `alter` to:

```
...
    function alter(func, replacer) {
        var newFunc = replacer(eval('window.' + funcName).toString());
        eval.call(window, newFunc);
    }
...
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = function () { var secret=0x09F91102; }
...
after('Foo.prototype.bar', 'return secret;');
```

Note the first argument to the functions are now strings. Further improvements could be made to handle methods that aren't accessible in global scope.

### Alternate approach

Instead of altering `doSomething`, it might be possible to wrap around the function/-s  that it calls which provide the data that `doSomething` uses to generate the ID (or, in general, whatever data is to be captured). There are some caveats:

- The called function can only be wrapped if it is in global scope, or code can be injected & run in the scope where it's defined.
- Wrapping the function will affect all code that uses it, not just `doSomething`, which may introduce bugs.
- If the called function doesn't return the data of interest directly but rather `doSomething` must process the result, then the wrapper must duplicate this processing (which violates the DRY principle). If the processing is minimal, this won't be a large issue, but is still a potential source of bugs (in particular, the code can get out of sync if the processing in `doSomething` is changed but the wrapper isn't).

Comment: This won't work in the general case because the function can execute a return at any time earlier so may not reach the injected code.

Comment: @TonyO'Hagan: thanks; that should be fixed now by the use of `try ... finally`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all your feedback. Each answer gave me a clue and as such I've come up with the following solution.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val;
    function doSomething(item1, item2) {
        var id = 3;
    }
    function merge() {
        var oScript = document.createElement("script");
        var oldDoSomething = doSomething.toString();
        oScript.language = "javascript";
        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
        var args = oldDoSomething.substring(oldDoSomething.indexOf("(") + 1, oldDoSomething.indexOf(")"));
        var scr = oldDoSomething.substring(oldDoSomething.indexOf("{") + 1, oldDoSomething.lastIndexOf("}") - 1);
        var newScript = "function doSomething(" + args + "){" + scr + " val = id; }";
        oScript.text = newScript;
        document.getElementsByTagName('BODY').item(0).appendChild(oScript);
    }

    merge();

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="doSomething();alert(val);" value="xx" />
```

Comment: A better solution (doesn't require DOM manipulation, is pure Javascript): http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134757/39722

Comment: @BernhardHofmann that doesn't actually solve the problem.   the question was specifically how-to-inject

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "locked" - JavaScript is interpreted by your browser.  Even if it has been minified or encoded, you can still copy the source of that function from source of the page of script.  At that point, you reassign the original function to one of your own design, which contains the copied code plus your own.

```
var id;
var myFunction = function() {
  // code copied from their source, which contains the variable needed

  // insert  your own code, such as for copying the needed value
  id = theirIDvalue;

  // return the value as originally designed by the function
  return theirValue;
};

theirObject.theirFunction = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function doSomething() { ... }
var oldVersionOfFunc = doSomething;
doSomething = function() {
    var retVal = oldVersionOfFunc.apply(oldVersionOfFunc, args);
    // your added code here
    return retVal;
}
```

This seems to provoke an error (Too much recursion)

```
function doSomething(){ document.write('Test'); return 45; } 
var code = 'myDoSomething = ' + doSomething + '; function doSomething() { var id = myDoSomething(); document.write("Test 2"); return id; }';
eval(code)
doSomething();
```

This works for me, even if it is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first class values in Javascript, which means that you can store them in variables (and in fact, declaring a named function is essentially assigning an anonymous function to a variable).

You should be able to do something like this:

```
function doSomething() { ... }

var oldVersionOfFunc = doSomething;
doSomething = function() {

    var retVal = oldVersionOfFunc.apply(oldVersionOfFunc, args);

    // your added code here

    return retVal;
}
```

(But, I could be wrong. My javascript's a little rusty. ;))

Comment: If I got the question right, that won't help here, since the problem is to extract the value of a local variable that's only referenced inside `doSomething`.  And the new version of `doSomething` can't reference variables inside the old one.

Answer (score 0):

> I can not change the doSomething function... Instead I need to somehow inject a few lines of code into the end of the doSomething code

Injecting a few lines into the end of the `doSomething` code sounds like changing the `doSomething` function, to me. I think, unfortunately, that you’re screwed.

(I’m a bit hazy on all this, but I think functions are how people who worry about such things implement information hiding in JavaScript, precisely because you can’t access their scope from outside them.)