# Javascript eval on global scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible to use the eval command to execute something with a global scope?  For example, this will cause an error:

```
<script>
 function execute(x){
 eval(x);
 }

 function start(){
  execute("var ary = new Array()");
  execute("ary.push('test');");  // This will cause exception: ary is not defined
 }

</script>
<html><body onLoad="start()"></body></html>
```

I know the 'with' keyword will set a specific scope, but is there a keyword for the global scope? Or is it possible to define a custom scope that would allow this to work?

```
<script>

 var scope = {};
 function execute(x){
  with(scope){
   eval(x);
  }
 }

 function start(){
  execute("var ary = new Array()");
  execute("ary.push('test');");  // This will cause exception: ary is not defined
 }

</script>
<html><body onLoad="start()"></body></html>
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is have a global execute funciton...

Answer (score 43):

```
(function(){
    eval.apply(this, arguments);
}(a,b,c))
```

This will invoke eval using the global object, `window` in browsers, as the `this` argument passing any arguments you've passed into the anonymous function.

`eval.call(window, x, y, z)` or `eval.apply(window, arguments)` is also valid if you're certain `window` is the global object. This isn't always true, however. For instance, the global object in a Node.js script is `process` if I remember correctly.

Comment: `eval.call(windwow,x); ` worked for me, cross-browser implementation. reason is, the global scope should always be the `window` object and subsequently defined functions will pertain to this object, as in `JSON.stringify` for example is nothing more than `window['JSON']['stringify']` and event `window['window']['window']['window']['window']['JSON']['stringify']`; both will still work.

Comment: This really helps! I had "Date" being set locally by the function calling me and I wanted the global version of the Date object which is window.Date.

Comment: -1. Read http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/ on what really happens.

Answer (score 10):

Use `(1, eval)('...')`.

```
$ node
> fooMaker = function () { (1, eval)('foo = "bar"'); };
[Function]
> typeof foo
'undefined'
> fooMaker()
undefined
> typeof foo
'string'
> foo
'bar'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of black magic is this, but it works amaizingly fine. I would love to understand what the heck is going on here, could you please explain? :)

Comment: @GonzaloLarralde : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107240/1-evalthis-vs-evalthis-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use `eval()` in global scope by calling it indirectly. However, not all browsers are currently doing this.

[Further Reading](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/).

Answer (score 3):

To execute some JavaScript in the global scope you can call it indirectly by using [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) or if you are using jQuery, take a look at [$.globalEval()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/).

Changing your execute method to the following will allow you to still use the 'var' keyword:

```
function execute(x) {
    setTimeout("eval(" + x + ")", 0);
    // Or: $.globalEval(x);
}


function start() {
    try
    {
        execute("var ary = new Array()");
        execute("ary.push('test');");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
}


start();
```

Comment: You'll need to properly quote whatever is in x (and you've left out a `+` after the x)

Comment: `$.globalEval(x);` worked great. More info found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921851/jquery-globaleval-function

Comment: You can also `setTimeout(x, 0)`, no need to wrap it in `"eval(" + x + ")"`

Answer (score 1):

I know there will be lot of comments coming in with eval is evil and I agree with that.
However, to answer your question, change your start method as follows:

```
function start(){   
  execute("ary = new Array()");   
  execute("ary.push('test');");  // This will cause exception: ary is not defined  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval.apply(null, ["code"]);`.

`eval.apply(this, ["code"]);` does not work on Microsoft Script Host (cscript.exe).

Example:

```
> type test.js
eval.apply(null, ["a=3;"]);
WScript.Echo(a);

> cscript test.js
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host 버전 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

3
```

Comment: Neither of these seem to work in a cscript context (along with every other "answer" here which assumes we're in a browser).