# jQuery .globalEval() function

Tags: jquery

I stumbled upon the function `.globalEval()` from browsing the jQuery source. There is very brief [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) which I don't understand. Apparently, it is "important for loading external scripts dynamically". Why? The source is also somewhat obscure:

```
globalEval: function( data ) {
    if ( data && rnotwhite.test( data ) ) {
        // We use execScript on Internet Explorer
        // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
        // rather than jQuery in Firefox
        ( window.execScript || function( data ) {
            window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );
        } )( data );
    }
},
```

Do people actually use this in real life? If so, for what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is used, as the name suggests, to execute the `eval` code in the global context. For example, consider the following ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGXwX/)):

```
function example(){
  $.globalEval("var example1 = 'first';");
  eval("var example2 = 'second';");
    console.log("In function: " + example1); //Prints 'first'
    console.log("In function: " + example2); //Prints 'second'
}
example();
console.log("Global: " + example1); //Prints 'first'
console.log("Global: " + example2); //ReferenceError
```

Because `example1` was defined using `globalEval`, it's in the global scope. Using plain old normal `eval`, the variable is only availble in the scope in which `eval` is called.

It can be useful if you want to load another JS script, and you want to execute that script in the global context (for example, above, we might need `example1` to be available outside of the `example` function, so we have to use `globalEval`.

I'm not sure why the jQuery source uses `window[ "eval" ].call` instead of just `eval.call`, but I'm sure someone could explain :)

Comment: For me, `(window.execScript || window.eval)(data)` seems to work, which is even simpler.

Comment: @Neil - I don't think it will work in older browsers (probably why jQuery provides a cross-browser method for it). This is now being discussed in a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922073/why-write-window-eval-call-window-data/