# Why write `window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );`

Tags: jquery

Line 614 of jQuery 1.7rc1:

`window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );`

Why not simply write

`eval.call( window, data );`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is here: [Decoding jQuery](http://www.blog.highub.com/javascript/decoding-jquery-evaluates-a-script-in-a-global-context/),

> Jim Driscoll found out that for more standards-respecting browsers,
>   you could use eval.call(window,data), but for Chrome and IE, things
>   are a bit different.
>
> Internet Explorer:  It seems that IE uses window.execScript(data)
>
> Chrome: eval.call(window,data) breaks on Chrome, but window[ "eval"
>   ].call( window, data) works on Chrome, and as well as other non-IE
>   browsers, this is how the above workarounds based upon.

Comment: I didn't write the reason only found an explanation.... Could be Chrome 14 is just more up to standards than older versions and since jquery aims to be cross browser and not just current browser they kept it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. I was just noting that it does work in Chrome 14. jQuery will have to keep it in for as long as browsers in which it does not work are around (which will be forever!)

Answer (score 4):

After looking at the [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7b1.js), I have found [this link](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/09/08/eval-javascript-global-context). Have a look at the emphasized text:

> **Sadly, `eval.call(window,src)` breaks on Chrome - it complains about
>   contexts not matching. Odd - and I was unable to Google up why this
>   might be so. But a couple lucky guesses later, and I discovered that
>   window.eval.call(window,src) works on all non-IE browsers.** Now, when I
>   say "var j = 1", the window[j] is the variable that's set... So,
>   that's good. Why do we have to add the extra window. on Chrome? Not
>   sure - I could guess, but it's too likely to be wrong.

So, `window.eval` is used to get `globalEval` work in Chrome.

Comment: It seems to work fine in Chrome 14. But that article is from 2009, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was a Chrome bug that's now fixed.

Comment: @JamesAllardice There're still users who don't use the newest version of Chrome. jQuery is designed to support as many browsers as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just noting that it does now work in Chrome. Of course, jQuery will have to keep the old-Chrome fix in there for as long as old-Chrome is around.

Comment: @Neil I just realised that the current answers haven't explained *why* `window.eval` is necessary. Have a look at this source, which is a very thorough analysis of the `eval` method: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/#eval_context_in_webkit

Comment: Thanks for that link, it explains that `window.eval.call(window,src)` is unnecessarily long-winded. In fact, `(window.execScript || eval)(src)` should suffice. (If you don't want to use execScript then `window.eval(src)` is the next best thing.)