# how to load an external html page(Html tags along with script functions) into the current page(DOM)

Tags: jquery

test1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js">
</script>
<script>

function loadfn(){

$.get('test.html',function(data){

alert($(data).text());
//$('body div#returnData').html(data);
$.each(data, function(i, node) { 
    alert(i);
   if (node.tagName == "SCRIPT") {
       eval(node.innerHTML); 

   } else {
       $(node).appendTo($('#returnData')); 
   }

});

});
test1();
test2();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="returnData" >
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick=loadfn()>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js">
</script>
</head>
<script>
function test1(){
alert('test1 function');
}
</script>
<script>
function test2(){
alert('test2 function');
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="testdiv">
Text field : <input type="text" value="Test Value"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually i have the requirement that i have to load the test.html page into test1.html and then run the script functions that are there in the test.html page.

The Above code snippet doesnt suffice the requirement. Please let me know what i am doing wrong in the code snippet.

Comment: in the $.get set the return type like $.get('url,'data',callback(),'html')

Comment: the scripts are not getting loaded..

Answer (score 0):

the functions are available soonest when the content is rendered... the problem is that the ajax call is asynchronously and therefore test1 and test2 do not exist when called in your example

untested but try:

```
function loadfn(){
  $.get('test.html',function(data){
    $('#returnData').html(data);
    test1();
    test2();
  });
}
```

EDIT: In test.html `html`, `head` and `body` tag should not be needed, place the script tag with the file inside the content because you are loading a sub part of the html and not a whole new page

Comment: The html page test.html is used seperately for some other request,so the html,head and body tags are required.I cant be changed to have only script tags with function.

Comment: then you should extract the common part to be loaded as separate call and include directly in the other request... now you would have to do expensive parsing and evil eval

Comment: i want to load the html page along with the javascript functions.

Comment: just tested it... seems to work even with the whole content of test.html :) so no changes... just load it asynchronously and use .html()

Comment: ya the above example works fine..But i have similar requirement where only change is we have to load a jsp. There i am getting error in jquery js stating that error in eval function...Is it different in loading a jsp than an html...Plz guide me..

Comment: actually i have to load all the js from the jsp page and load a part of the jsp page into the current page (DOM)

Comment: sorry I have no knowledge about jsp. of course there could be a problem... starting with the returned header, the file name that is requested, the data that is created by that jsp and more aspects...

Comment: i am getting error while jquery js try to execute globalEval function ...check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922073/why-write-window-eval-call-window-data/  firebug points  error at this line of the jquery js...

Comment: what should that question tell me? as said I have no knowledge about jsp so I do not how your response looks like. if it is like the html file and the header is right everything will work like in the above example... but I suppose your jsp output looks completely different (content as well as header)