# Check syntax of JavaScript(jQuery) code before running jQuery.globalEval() or eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Continuing with topic: [jQuery .globalEval() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921851/jquery-globaleval-function)

I use jQuery.globalEval(varwithJScode);

Now the problem starts when code in varwithJScode contains syntax or other error - the whole script stops.

jsFiddle does not support jQuery.globalEval(), but I used eval() instead to simulate.

http://jsfiddle.net/55FfW/
Try changing var codeforeval to some wrong javascript code and next command will fail.

Is there a way to avoid other JS code from stopping in case of error and/or is there a way to check syntax before eval?

Tried using this one:

```
try {
   jQuery.globalEval(jscode);
} catch (e) {
   if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
      alert('JS error!');
   }
}
```

Does not work for me!

Comment: jsfiddle supports jQuery, you just have to choose the jquery library on the left...

Comment: @DidierGhys: Why do you think I did not do this?

Comment: jsfiddle let me use `.globalEval()` with no problems when I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/55FfW/1/) or tried [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGXwX/) from the accepted answer from the other question that you linked to. This one worked with a try/catch too: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/55FfW/3/

Comment: @nnnnnn: interesting. I tried globalEval() on jsfiddle many times and it did not work until I changed it to eval(). And I never forget to choose jQuery framework. The solution is actually to remove (instanceof SyntaxError) and leave just (e) from my code. Thanks!

Comment: I have created a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55FfW/4/), and cannot reproduce the results in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            try {
                jQuery.globalEval(data.js);
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
```

Comment: Note that if you have a window.onerror handler, it will be called if an error is encountered in this eval.  you can temp assign null to window.onerror to avoid this (restoring window.onerror afterwards).  Of course, using eval in any form should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need not a heavy jQuery to do such a simple thing.

Just assign `eval` to a variable and then call it.

```
    try{
         var globalEval = eval;
         globalEval(jscode);   //execute in global scope
    } catch(e) {
         alert(e);
    }
```