# chrome extension Cannot read property 'currentScript' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have XHR request defined in my chrome extension which pulls out a javascript file from specific website and execute a function within it. Like this:

```
//This will return the remote JS file content
function _curl(url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('get', 'https://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/' + url, false);
      xhr.send();
      return xhr.responseText;
}

//Here I get the JS content and execute it
var rpt = _curl('https://my-page.com/remote.js').match(/\){([^]+)}/)[1]; 
eval(rpt); //This fails with the error "Cannot read property 'currentScript' of undefined"
```

The part of JS code in remote file where `currentScript` is defined is:

```
...
var Uh=window.document.currentScript&&-1!=window.document.currentScript.src.indexOf("?loadGamesSDK")?"/cast_game_sender.js":"/cast_sender.js",
...
```

Is this happening because I am trying to execute request in chrome environment? Because, I've also tried executing request within the page by `eval` contents, which worked. Its just whenever I try to execute same piece of code in my extension, it pops out with this error

Comment: This code is dubious in general (synchronous XHR? eval?), but the important part is: which part of the extension are you trying to run this in, and why it has to be a remote script?

Comment: And you have to know that the `eval()` function can't be use in google chrome extension. It's considered as an unsafe call and will throw an exception.

Comment: @Xan It is basically a plugin which depends on function defined in remote javascript file for calculation purpose. Without the function in their JS file, code is useless. This explains the remote script purpose. Is there any better way?
I am trying to run this in content script.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin I know it is totally unsafe and not recommended. Trust me, I am also trying to avoid it. But how am I supposed to execute a function in remote JS file? Is there any other way? Note that the remote JS is absolutely necessary. There is no way I can avoid it

Comment: It's not à question of good practice here. Google don't allow thé exécution of this function. You have to find an other way to do it. More generaly Google don't allow thé execution of external code and try to break all thé possibilities to execute external code

Comment: @Emrys, that's FUD, it's possible to use eval / remote code in extensions, safely too.

Comment: @Xan It's certainly possible to safely use `eval` in a Chrome extension, but not with the code as shown in the OP, and only for exceptional use cases: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't noticed that the script was running in background pages. It always had the `window.document` property. However, since `eval` was failing, I tried replacing it with [`jQuery.globalEval`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.globaleval/) and it worked.

The reason why it worked, I think is that `eval` was not being executed in global environment, which `jQuery.globalEval` provided. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7921955/1136491) explain a bit more about this behaviour.

The working code now looks like:

```
//This will return the remote JS file content
function _curl(url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('get', 'https://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/' + url, false);
      xhr.send();
      return xhr.responseText;
}

//Here I get the JS content and execute it
var rpt = _curl('https://my-page.com/remote.js').match(/\){([^]+)}/)[1]; 
jQuery.globalEval(rpt); //This works now
```