# (1, eval)('this') vs eval('this') in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eval

I start to read [JavaScript Patterns](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/), some [codes](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/access-to-global-object.html) confused me.

```
var global = (function () {
    return this || (1, eval)('this');
}());
```

Here are my questions:

Q1:

> `(1, eval) === eval`?

Why and how does it work?

Q2: Why not just

```
var global = (function () {
    return this || eval('this');
}());
```

or

```
 var global = (function () {
    return this;
}());
```

Comment: I have updated the title because this is a specific case. Also, *parenthesis* for the specific kind of *brackets*: [] and {} are different entirely :)

Comment: Since [optional chaining](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) made it into the spec, indirect eval has a slightly less obfuscated syntax: `eval?.(`…`)` (instead of `(1, eval)(`…`)`). Since this is an [_OptionalExpression_](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-OptionalExpression) and not a [_CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead_](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead), as necessitated for [direct eval](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation), this is also an indirect eval.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The difference between `(1,eval)` and plain old `eval` is that the former is a *value* and the latter is an lvalue.  It would be more obvious if it were some other identifier:

```
var x;
x = 1;
(1, x) = 1; //  syntax error, of course!
```

That is `(1,eval)` is an expression that yields `eval` (just as say, `(true && eval)` or `(0 ? 0 : eval)` would), but it's not a reference to `eval`.

Why do you care?

Well, the Ecma spec considers a *reference* to `eval` to be a "direct eval call", but an expression that merely yields `eval` to be an indirect one -- and indirect eval calls are guaranteed to execute in global scope.

Things I still don't know:

1. Under what circumstance does a direct eval call *not* execute in global scope?
2. Under what circumstance can the `this` of a function at global scope *not* yield the global object?

Some more information can be gleaned [here](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/).

**EDIT**

Apparently, the answer to my first question is, "almost always".  A direct `eval` executes from the *current* scope.  Consider the following code:

```
var x = 'outer';
(function() {
  var x = 'inner';
  eval('console.log("direct call: " + x)'); 
  (1,eval)('console.log("indirect call: " + x)'); 
})();
```

Not surprisingly (heh-heh), this prints out:

```
direct call: inner
indirect call: outer
```

**EDIT**

After more experimentation, I'm going to provisionally say that `this` cannot be set to `null` or `undefined`.  It can be set to other falsy values (0, '', NaN, false), but only *very* deliberately.

I'm going to say your source is suffering from a mild and reversible cranio-rectal inversion and might want to consider spending a week programming in Haskell.

Comment: Wow, didn't know the whole `value` vs `lvalue` thing (well, in practice maybe, but not in words). Nor the ES5 eval rules (not that I should reasonably need to use `eval` ever). Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `eval` has a lot of nasty sharp edges and should only be used as a last resort and then, very, very carefully.

Comment: I only once came across a valid use - evaluating a script tag that had been added to the DOM via `innerHtml`

Comment: lvalue has little to due with determining direct eval since it usually refers the expression that can appear on the left hand side of an assignment, hence the name lvalue as opposed to rvalue. A call to eval is direct only under the conditions listed in 15.1.2.1.1 of the spec which says the identifier must be `eval` and be the MemberExpression part of a CallExpression and refer to the standard `eval` function.

Comment: @chuckj -- `lvalue` was just my simplification of the situation.

Comment: @Malvolio You seem to be implying that lvalues have something to do with direct vs. indirect eval which they don't. The use of an identifier called `eval` as the target of a call expression is special. You state that ECMA treats _reference_ to `eval` special which it doesn't. It is the placement in the call expression that is special an that the expression evaluates to the standard `eval` function. For example, `var eval = window.eval; eval('1');` is still a direct eval and `window.eval('1')` isn't even though eval is an lvalue in this case as well.

Comment: Did you get an answer to question 2?  How on earth can 'this' not be global?

Comment: I"d like to know WHEN one would use this convention? If I understand the indirect vs. direct - great, but WHEN would this be useful for me? Any practical real world examples?

Comment: I try to avoid calling `eval` ever.  I have an inchoate theory that the distinction is made for the security of the browser and the browser's user, not for the convenience of the programmer.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer when you use either apply or method call invocation say ({q: function() { console.log(this, eval('this'), (0, eval)('this'), window.eval('this'));}}).q(); window.eval return Window because it uses method call invocation from parent Window

Comment: @hurtchin yes of course, but look at the question more closely. Here the containing closure is not being passed up for calling later, its being invoked immediately.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer yeah, you are right. I overlooked it's IIFE. Than I guess it'll only be different in strict mode as chuckj suggest.

Answer (score 36):

The fragment

```
var global = (function () {  
    return this || (1, eval)('this');  
}());
```

will correctly evaluate to the global object even in strict mode. In non-strict mode the value of `this` is the global object but in strict mode it is `undefined`. The expression `(1, eval)('this')` will always be the global object.

The reason for this involves the rules around indirect versus direct `eval`. Direct calls to `eval` has the scope of the caller and the string `this` would evaluate to the value of `this` in the closure. Indirect `eval`s evaluate in global scope as if they were executed inside a function in the global scope.

Since that function is not itself a strict-mode function the global object is passed in as `this` and then the expression `'this'` evaluates to the global object. The expression `(1, eval)` is just a fancy way to force the `eval` to be indirect and return the global object.

A1: `(1, eval)('this')` is not the same as `eval('this')` because of the special rules around indirect versus direct calls to `eval`.

A2: The original works in strict mode, the modified versions do not.

Answer (score 12):

To Q1:

I think this is a good example of comma operator in JS. I like the explanation for comma operator in this article: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

To Q2:

`(1, eval)('this')` is considered as indirect eval call, which in ES5 does execute code globally. So the result will be the global the context.

See http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/#evaling_in_global_scope

Answer (score 8):

Q1: Multiple consecutive javascript statements separated by a comma take the value of the last statement.  So:

`(1, eval)` takes the value of the last one which is a function reference to the `eval()` function.  It apparently does it this way to make the `eval()` call into an indirect eval call that will be evaluated in the global scope in ES5.  Details explained [here](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/).

Q2: There must be some environment that doesn't define a global `this`, but does define `eval('this')`.  That's the only reason I can think of for that.

Comment: Perhaps someone's trying to dodge a check-in hook that disallows `/eval\(/g`?

Comment: @Stoive - yeah I wondered about something like that too.  If not a checkin hook, some filter somewhere in the process (perhaps minimization).

Comment: It has something to do with ES5 strict mode. AFAIK in ES5 strict mode any `eval`'d code is executed in its own context rather than in the global context or the enclosing context. One way around this is to indirectly reference it as the code in question does.

Comment: Have a look at "[Global eval. What are the options?](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/)".

Comment: Updated my answer to include the info from CDSanchez and @Saxoier.  Thx.