# why this code doesn't run?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
(function () {
    "use strict";


    function initialize() {
        myList = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    }

    function displayList() {
        var i, n;
        for (i = 0, n = myList.length; i < n; i += 1) {
            alert(myList[i]);
        }
    }
    initialize();
    displayList();

})();
```

if not using var, the myList variable will supposedly be created as a globle variable. Either way, the code should be running. What is wrong with the code??

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397778/how-to-declare-global-variables-when-using-the-strict-mode-pragma

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I run this code in jsfiddle; I dont get any error message...

Comment: Because [you get an error message](http://jsbin.com/UsuKUgas/1/edit?js,console): *ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable myList (line 15)*

Comment: bcz you told you are strict , but you are not :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myList = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

In strict mode, you are not allowed to create global variables in this way.

From official Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors) -

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"
>   (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript).
>   Assignments which would accidentally create global variables instead
>   throw in strict mode:
>
> "use strict";
>
> mistypedVaraible = 17; // throws a ReferenceError

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/TajtW/) -

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var myList;

    function initialize() {
        myList = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    }

    function displayList() {
        var i, n;
        for (i = 0, n = myList.length; i < n; i += 1) {
            alert(myList[i]);
        }
    }

    initialize();
    displayList();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set global variables like that when in strict mode.

You'll have to do

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var myList;

    function initialize() {
        myList = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    }

    function displayList() {
        var i, n;
        for (i = 0, n = myList.length; i < n; i += 1) {
            alert(myList[i]);
        }
    }
    initialize();
    displayList();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `"use strict"` you're limiting yourself to strict mode (which is a good thing), but that means you can't just use a variable that hasn't been set yet.

If you want to define `myList` as a global variable, you'll have to do that before the function starts, so at the top of the script put: `var myList;`