# JS Scoping of functions / global variables

Tags: javascript

I read that it is usually best to include your javascript code within a function block like so

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // stuff here
}());
```

But if the code is meant to be globally accessible, a function or a constant for example, is that ok to be outside of a function block or should I set it up in another way?

Also - if I moved the code outside of the function block JSLint, for example, [would suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462478/jslint-is-suddenly-reporting-use-the-function-form-of-use-strict) I move the `use strict` statement inside a function block.  Would just have to be a concession I would have to make?

Comment: Why downvote without a comment? How does that help anyone?

Comment: It seems like you're using a pattern without really understanding *why*: a good example of cargo cultism. You should dig deeper and find alternatives to global functions/variables. (This isn't related to downvoting.)

Comment: @t.niese That looks great thanks. Juhana I know why I'm using it, I just didn't how to scope my code appropriately whilst having global functions.  I thought the point of SO was that you could ask questions you don't know the answer to?

Comment: @Chris sorry was about to fix a typo, and accidentally hit delete. [How to declare global variables when using the strict mode pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397778)

Comment: @Juhana I have a file that provides helper functionality to an Angular ViewModel. Arguably it could be written as a directive but I didn't write the code, another developer did, and I don't have time to completely rewrite it & test it. I was just updating it be inside a function block (as I had related MVC bundling issues) when I realised I didn't know the best practice in this situation

Comment: @Chris Well downvotes are opinion based. It is not wrong to ask questions, but e.g. if passing `use strict global variables` to a search engine shows as first result the one I linked to, it is likely that you will get a down vote, as you neither linked to that question nor explain why your question differs from that one. But as I said I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Setting things up inside of a function has benefits, it means that private variables which are not exposed remain private. You can expose things to the outside world by `return`ing things from that function.

```
var module = (function() {
    "use strict";
    var private = "This is private!";
    var publicFn = function() { return "This is public!"; };

    return {
        myFunction: publicFn;
    };
})();

module.myFunction(); // This is public
```

As for using `"use strict"` only inside functions, it's because authors often concatenate and minify multiple JavaScript files, and using `"use strict"` outside the function scope will affect all other files in the chain (which is sometimes not the intended behavior and can cause bugs).