# Unusual javascript syntax

Tags: javascript

could someone please explain to me what is going on in the second line here ? :

```
var foo = function(){alert("hello?")};
(0,foo)();
```

Comment: @ubercooluk – There is no sign of jQuery there at all.

Comment: @Alex — No, it isn't. There are no variables being enclosed. Are you confusing a function expression with a closure? Function expressions are often used to create closures, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @Funky, are you sure `foo` is defined this way and is not an object method (`(0, obj.foo)()`)? The call semantics will not be the same if this is the case.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The infamous comma expression `a,b` evaluates both arguments and returns the value of the right-hand expression.

Hence in this case it's exactly the same as `foo();`.

[Here's a better example](http://ideone.com/XlMvtU) that will help you understand what's going on:

```
function foo() {
    print("foo called");
    return 123;
}
function bar() {
    print("bar called");
    return 456;
}
var result = (foo(), bar());
print("result:", result);
```

Output:

```
foo called
bar called
result: 456
```

Also the comma expression may be confused with the comma delimiting function arguments. Not the same! Notice the difference:

```
print("result:", foo(), bar() ); // 3 arguments, no comma operator
print("result:", (foo(), bar()) ); // 2 arguments, comma operator
```

Comment: (The comma operator also has the undocumented feature of causing funny bugs when someone makes a typo.)

Comment: Thanks @Kos, your explanation makes sense. The snippet is based on code from a complex and well written 3rd party tool and yet it is overly complex. I assume maybe the 0 used to be something more substantial which was replaced by the 0 as a placeholder ?

Comment: Or the right side may have been replaced.  (0,eval)() is a way of calling indirect evals, which are used to protect global scope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107240/1-evalthis-vs-evalthis-in-javascript

Answer (score 9):

It's evaluating both expressions in the first parenthesis and executing the second one (in this case - a function).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 2):

Since the Comma operator in javascript evaluates multiple operands and returns the last one.   MDN:

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

Your expression `(0,foo)`

returns `foo` which then is invoked by the paranthesis, put after it.

Answer (score 1):

the comma will evaluate operands and return the last one

the second line will return **foo**