# How does indirect eval work

Tags: javascript

I saw on the Internet that people using following construction to get Global object

```
(1,eval)('this')
```

or this

```
(0||eval)('this')
```

Could you explain how exactly does it work and the benefit over `window`, `top`, etc.?

**UPD**: testing direct vs. indirect `eval` calls: http://kangax.github.io/jstests/indirect-eval-testsuite/

Comment: What's wrong with `window` or `top`?

Comment: For me - nothing is wrong, but I want to know what is the point of doing this. For me - it is a black magic without any profit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107240/1-evalthis-vs-evalthis-in-javascript

Comment: Interesting... thanks.

Comment: I had never heard of this construct prior to reading this question, but I guess you learn something new every day :-)

Comment: To answer your last question, window and top only work on browsers.

Comment: bfavaretto, I know. But I meant other non-magic versions, like pass `window` or `global` to IIFE

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/ should leave no open questions.

Answer (score 2):

`(1,eval)('this')` is equivalent to `eval('this')`

`(0||eval)('this')` is equivalent to `eval('this')`

So (1, eval) or (0 || eval) is an expression which **yields** eval

Like in:

```
var x = 2;
console.log( (10000, x) );  // will print 2 because it yields the second variable
console.log( (x, 10000) );  // will print 10000 because it yields the second literal
console.log( (10000 || x) ); // will print 10000 because it comes first in an OR
                             // expression
```

The only **catch** here it that an object returned from an expression is always the object having the most global scope.

Check that code:

```
x = 1;

function Outer() {
    var x = 2;
    console.log((1, eval)('x')); //Will print 1
    console.log(eval('x')); //Will print 2
    function Inner() {
        var x = 3;
        console.log((1, eval)('x')); //Will print 1
        console.log(eval('x')); //Will print 3
    }
    Inner();
}

Outer();
```