# Strange JavaScript Function Call Construct (0, <function>)()

Tags: javascript

Code in the wild:

```
return function decorateSource(DecoratedComponent) {
    return (0, _decorateHandler2.default)({
        connectBackend: function connectBackend(backend, sourceId) {
            return backend.connectDragSource(sourceId);
        },
        containerDisplayName: 'DragSource',
        createHandler: createSource,
        registerHandler: _registerSource2.default,
        createMonitor: _createSourceMonitor2.default,
        createConnector: _createSourceConnector2.default,
        DecoratedComponent: DecoratedComponent,
        getType: getType,
        collect: collect,
        options: options
    });
};
```

And the construct in question:

`(0, _decorateHandler2.default)(...)`

***What is going on with this wrapped statement?***

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107240/1-evalthis-vs-evalthis-in-javascript/9107367#9107367

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to doing this:

```
(function(){
    // do something
})();
```

In that because the element is wrapped in parentheses gets treated as a value, and the last value in the parentheses is being executed as a function by the following parentheses. The `0,` isn't doing anything. Removing `0,` won't change how the code is run, so in this case I figure `0,` is just obfuscation as whatever `_decorateHandler2.default` returns is what `decorateSource` returns. The benefit of doing this (or the code sample above) is that you're creating a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that help you control the scope of your variables and not pollute the global scope.