# Get the names of the parameters of the wrapped function

Tags: javascript

I want to use the methods of the `Minio` class without specifying all their parameters, but substituting some of the parameters automatically. How do I do it...

1. I get all the class methods from the prototype of the `Minio` class and dynamically create wrappers for them in my class.
2. For each wrapper method, I get the parameter names from the original method of the Test class.
3. If there is one in the list of parameters that I want to omit when calling my wrapper method, then I add it to the list of arguments and call `originalMethod.apply(this.minioClient, args)`.

Everything was fine until there were methods that were already wrapped.
I need to get the parameter list of the `bucketExists` method from outside the `Minio` class. Any idea how to get parameter names from such a wrapped method?

```js
// minio/dist/main/helpers.js
exports function promisify(fn){
  return function(){
    const args = [...arguments];
    fn.apply(this, args);
  }
}

// minio/dist/main/minio.js
class Minio{
  bucketExists(bucketName){
    return bucketName;
  }
  methodThatNotWrappedByPromisifyAndWorksFine(bucketName){
    return bucketName;
  }
}

module.exports = Minio;
Minio.prototype.bucketExists = (0,helpers.promisify)(Minio.prototype.bucketExists)
```

I want to give an instance of my class with methods wrapped from the original class [link](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/master/src/main/minio.js) the ability to work with only one bucket, that was passed to the my class constructor, without the ability to specify some other one after initialize.

My wrapper

```js
    const proxyHandler = () => {
      return {
        apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
          const funcParams = getMethodParamNames(target.source ? target.source.functionForWrap : target);
          const bucketNameIndex = funcParams.indexOf("bucketName");
          const regionNameIndex = funcParams.indexOf("region");

          if (bucketNameIndex >= 0) {
            argumentsList.splice(bucketNameIndex, 0, this.bucket.name);
          }
          if (regionNameIndex >= 0) {
            argumentsList.splice(regionNameIndex, 0, this.bucket.region);
          }
          try {
            return target.apply(this.minioClient, argumentsList);
          } catch (error) {
            logger.engine.error(`S3 '${this.bucket.name}' ${target} error: ${error.message}`, error.stack);
          }
        },
      }
    }

    getMethods(this.minioClient).forEach(func => {
      this[func] = new Proxy(this.minioClient[func], proxyHandler());
    })
```

Solved the problem by overriding the method wrapper like this.

```js
const MinioHelpers = require('minio/dist/main/helpers');

const origMinioPromisify = MinioHelpers.promisify;

MinioHelpers.promisify = (functionForWrap) => {
    console.log("PATCHED!", functionForWrap);
    var fn = origMinioPromisify(functionForWrap);
    //from this i'll get all need information about wrapped function
    fn.source = {
        functionForWrap,
        promisify: origMinioPromisify,
    } 
    return fn
}

var Minio = require('minio');
```

Comment: Do you need to create wrappers, or can you modify the original functions?

Comment: @MichaelM.Test class is an external module [link](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/master/src/main/minio.js), i can't modify it, I want to create wrappers.

Comment: Since parameters in Javascript are always positional, it's not a good idea to look specifically for parameter *names*, as these are usually subject to change. Not only by the programmer, but by tools like minifiers.

Comment: @deceze I want to give an instance of my class with methods wrapped from the original class [link](https://github.com/minio/minio-js/blob/master/src/main/minio.js) the ability to work with only one bucket that was passed to the class constructor, without the ability to specify some other one.
Most, but not all, methods accept a bucketName as a parameter.
I can't just look at the position of the parameter, I also need its name because some methods don't accept bucketName.

Comment: [Proxy/handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) ?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston 
```const handler = {  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {}}; ```

At target i'm still stuck in the wrapper 
```return function(){
    const args = [...arguments];
    fn.apply(this, args);
  }``` 
and can't access original method...

Comment: @twistedmind what this means? `(0,promisify)(Minio.prototype.bucketExists)`. I understand the promisify function but what does the (0, promisify) does?

Comment: @hawk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724776/strange-javascript-function-call-construct-0-function