# What is "this" in javascript when calling a method on a calculated object?

Tags: javascript, this

I know `this` is probably the second most asked-about thing in javascript, right after floating point arithmetic.

I generally know how `this` works, and how it's affected by arrow functions, `.call()`, `.apply()`, and `.bind()`.  I thought I understood everything about it.  But I do not.

In a web browser, `document.createElement("div").classList.add("c")` yields `undefined` as expected.  However, this expression surprisingly is an error.

```
(true && document.createElement("div").classList.add)("c")
```

I expected it to be the same, but it's

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at <anonymous>:1:54
```

Comment: What is purpose of expression and call `(true && document.createElement("div").classList.add)("c")`?

Comment: In my understanding, its got to do with `()`. When you write anything inside `()`, it becomes an expression and they have their own context. So when you try to evaluate `.add`, the context of element has been destroyed and hence error

Comment: @guest271314 It makes the function call indirect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107240/1-evalthis-vs-evalthis-in-javascript

Comment: @guest271314:  The purpose of the expression is to illustrate the question.

Comment: Perhaps not certain what you are trying to achieve? Call `.add()`?

Comment: @JJJ For what purpose?

Comment: @Anil:  I assume you mean "undefined".  If it is undefined, then why did the first call succeed?

Comment: @guest271314:  This is the minimum code that expresses the question.  I adapted it from real application code, but this is not real application code.  This code exists only to illustrate the question.

Comment: @recursive, i got it, later i removed my comment :)

Comment: @recursive Still not certain what you are trying to achieve by using the pattern? What is expected result?

Comment: @recursive, function add is expecting native code function `add() {
    [native code]
}`

Comment: @guest271314: I'm trying to understand javascript.  I expect the two statements to work the same way.

Comment: @Anil: `add()` isn't expectign native code.  It *is* native code.

Comment: @recursive Does `var el = document.createElement("div"); el.classList.add("c");` not yield expected result? Why is the pattern at Question necessary?

Comment: @guest271314: Your code does yield the expected result.  The code in the question is necessary to illustrate the question.  If I changed it to your code, it wouldn't support the question.  The code exists *only* to illustrate the question.

Comment: @recursive Am trying to understand Question. Have re-read, will re-read again.

Comment: @recursive If you chain `.classList.add("c")` to expression `undefined` is result `(true && document.createElement("div")).classList.add("c")`, `(true && document.createElement("div"))["classList"]["add"]("c")` though not sure if chaining to `()` is part of Question?

Answer (score 5):

Your statement

`(true && document.createElement("div").classList.add)("c")`  can also be rewritten as following:

```
var add = (true && document.createElement("div").classList.add)
add("c")
```

[Logical AND (&&) expr1 && expr2 : **Returns** expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, **returns** expr2.]

You see that function `add` is now part of `window` and loses reference of actual `classList` object and hence cannot be called correctly.

add's `this` now points to global object.

If you do following (if the new div is the only div on your page), it again has reference to the original object:

```
(true && document.createElement("div").classList.add).bind(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].classList)("c")
```

Comment: How do you know it can equivalently be re-written that way?  That's not obvious to me.

Comment: that is not exactly equivalent, and was rewritten to explain your query,

Comment: Logical AND (&&) expr1 && expr2 : Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

so using ```&&``` in your statement is like extracting function from ```classList``` object and then calling the orphan function

Answer (score 3):

This will work, as it is returning `this` as `classlist` context

```
(document.createElement("div").classList.add)("c")
```

`(true && document.createElement("div").classList.add)` will not work as `add` is getting evaluated  with && expression and after this its returning context of the expression `(true && document.createElement("div").classList.add)` which is `add() { [native code] }` and not classList and here we are trying to call add on add function.

When you are trying pass class name `("c")` to `add` then this is not `classlist` any more hence `Illegal invocation`

Answer (score -7):

What you are tryng to do doesnt make sense.
Maybe you mean

```
var added document.createElement("div").classList.add("c")
If (added){...….}
```

In your example you have a ) too much after add