# Jscript: is it possible to set the variable dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jscript, wsh

In **config.txt**, I have the following strings:

```
Dispatcher=argo
Address=10.5.23.14
User=joe
```

In my **script.js**, I have the variables:

```
var Dispatcher, Address, User;
```

In script.js, I read config.txt, parse strings and get name/value pairs:

```
ConfigPair = ConfigString.split("=");
VarName = ConfigPair[0];
VarValue = ConfigPair[1];
```

What I want is to assign VarValue to the VarName variable. Say, if I get "Address" in VarName and "10.5.23.14" in VarValue, I want to set Address variable to 10.5.23.14.

I **don't want** to do something like that:

```
if (VarName == "Dispatcher") {
    Dispatcher = VarValue;
} else if (VarName == "Address") {
    Address = VarValue;
} else if bla-bla-bla
```

I want to somehow "**read**" the value of VarName and assign VarValue to the corresponding variable. Is it possible to do it in Windows Script Host (JScript)? I played with **eval**, but failed to make it work. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work in a browser you can use the global `window` object like so :

```
// VarName = "User"
// VarValue = "joe"
window[VarName] = VarValue;
alert(User); // prints "joe"
User = 'jack';
alert(User); // prints "jack"
```

---

### Edit

Tested with WSH and Windows 7 :

```
(function () {
    var VarName = 'User'; // ConfigPair[0]
    var VarValue = 'joe'; // ConfigPair[1]
    this[VarName] = VarValue;
})();
WSH.Echo(User); // prints "joe"
WSH.Quit();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not in the browser. Windows Script Host, running cscript script.js from command line.

Comment: I have found a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642491/getting-a-reference-to-the-global-object-in-an-unknown-environment-in-strict-mod) telling that you can access the global object like so : `var GLOBAL = (function(){return this}());`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object and assign properties dynamically,

```
var VarHolder = {};

VarHolder[VarName] = VarValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful. That being said, no way to directly assign to the variable, correct? I want to redefine variable in the script if there is a corresponding string in the config. With your solution I can do this: var Dispatcher="disp1"; if VarHolder["Dispatcher"] {Dispatcher=VarHolder["Dispatcher"]. it is OK, but isn't there more compact/simple way?

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question right, then [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4670805) may help.

```
(function() { eval.apply(this, arguments); }("x=1;y=2"));
WScript.Echo("x=" + x, "y=" + y); // x=1 y=2
```