# Firing method when another method completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that has a method attached to the onclick event.  I am unable to edit the existing html or javascript method but I am able to add additional javascript.

I need to fire some jquery after the `fixedMethod()` method completes.

So for example in the sample below I need to make the output `1, 2` instead of `2, 1` without changing the HTML of the link or `fixedMethod()` but the rest of the javascript I can change.

This is a contrived example, in my actual use case I don't know how long the method will take to complete.

```js
function fixedMethod(){
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(1)}, 2000);
}

$("#someLink").click(function(){
  console.log(2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="someLink" href="#" onclick="fixedMethod()">click here</a>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What sort of method? If it's asynchronous and returns a Promise, call `then` on it? If it's not asynchronous, just call the second function right below?

Comment: @LGSon because I have no way to know how long fixedMethod() will take to complete

Comment: `in my actual use case I don't know how long the method will take to complete` nope, unless that function somehow can indicate its completion

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for confirming.

Comment: This might be an option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222618/append-code-to-the-end-of-an-existing-function

Comment: Unfortunately the method is not in same scope as where I can add my JS (different doc ready blocks)

Comment: If the method change the DOM, you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Ahh I think that will work!  The script modifies one of two locations depending on outcome so I can monitor them for changes :)