# Add code to a function in angular programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to add code to a function that is inside of ui-grid. I do not want to edit the existing code. How can I add code to an existing function, in angular, that does not edit the original code?

I tried using the concept from [Adding code to a javascript function programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134686/adding-code-to-a-javascript-function-programatically) but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: What function you try to modify?

Comment: I want to add code to the paginationApi.nextPage function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to find the scope and the function and modify it:

```
var $scope = $('[ng-click="paginationApi.nextPage()"]').scope();
var original_function = $scope.paginationApi.nextPage;
$scope.paginationApi.nextPage = function() {
    // do some stuff
    original_function.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: seems kind of strange to me that you're creating the var $scope and the paginationApi isn't available on angular's $scope.

Comment: @fauverism If you created ui-grid it's probably different inner scope, so you need to find it first.