# QuickBase: Load javascript file every time it searches in tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, quickbase

Okay, so I have a javascript file that launches which injects another javascript file which creates checkbox per row. The js loader file looks like this:

```
//Run these scripts on all table pages
if (gReqTemplName == "searchresults") {
    console.log(kRecordNamePlural, gReqQID);
    if ((kRecordNamePlural == "Time Cards" && gReqQID == 37) || (kRecordNamePlural == "Milestone Payments" && gReqQID == 11) || (kRecordNamePlural == "Expenses" && gReqQID == 11)) {
        $.getScript('/js/QuickBaseClient.js', function (data) {
            $.getScript(gReqAppDBID + '?a=dbpage&pagename=approve.js');
        });
    };
}
```

This specific pageID 37 table has search function. The problem is, When I do the search, the injected javascript doesn't work anymore. Meaning, the checkbox per row doesn't show anymore in the result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the report are erased and rewritten whenever the search box is used.  Since the page isn't reloaded to do this, whatever changes that `approve.js` made when it was loaded are not applied to the newly created elements.  You can use this technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134757/5100475) to make your code run after that report is updated.  The method you want to cache is `QB.Faceting.Instance.tableHomePageView.reportView.updateReport` and will look something like this:

```
QB.Faceting.Instance.tableHomePageView.reportView.updateReport = (function(){
    var cachedFunction = QB.Faceting.Instance.tableHomePageView.reportView.updateReport;
    return function(){
        var result = cachedFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        // Your code that inserts checkboxes
    };
})();
```

Note: This will stop working if Quickbase changes its method names or the way search boxes work.  If this is a critical business function you may want to write a custom page that handles its own layout and makes changes to records via API calls.  That way you're insulated from UI updates.