# Google tags manager. How to prevent loading custom tag programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm working on site that uses GTM(Google Tag Manager).
GTM includes some script(tag) from a site that not allowed in my country. It causes an error in console and I want to stop loading this tag. I don't have access to GTM account so I should do it with js. This script is `Custom HTML Tag` because when I try below code it stops loading:

```
    dataLayer = [{
        'gtm.blacklist':['html']
    }];
```

but it also stops loading other custom tags.
How can I stop loading certain custom tag programmatically?

Comment: Blacklisting html will prevent all custom scripts. Does this specific tag trigger from page load, or a specific trigger? Is it possible to isolate the trigger perhaps?

Comment: @CarlK  I'm new to GTM so I'm not sure but I got this console error while page loads so it should be triggered by page load right?

Comment: It is likely pageload then. It could still be an event that fires. You could check `window.dataLayer` and see which events have been passed to GTM and confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done. Looking into GTM code we can see it uses insertBefore function to add Script elements to website (for now, they can change this at any time). So in theory you can "add" some code to the native function and prevent loading of scripts from specific sources. For example, you can run following code before you load GTM:

```
Node.prototype.insertBefore = (function() {
    var cached_function = Node.prototype.insertBefore;

    return function(script) {
        if(script && script.src.indexOf("www.somesource.com/script.js") !== -1){ //change to src you don't want to load on your page
            return false; //don't add the script
        }else{
            var result = cached_function.apply(this, arguments); // use .apply() to call native function

            return result;
        }
    };
})();
```

(code taken from: [Adding code to a javascript function programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134686/adding-code-to-a-javascript-function-programmatically))

I didn't test this code, so I am not advising you to do it without proper testing or you might decide not to do it at all(before you do you might want to read: [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)). I agree with Eike's answer but all I am saying is that it is possible to prevent loading of custom tags programmatically.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with a small corrections that I added to your answer. Because `insertBefore` calls also for elements without `src` attribute we should check if `src` attribute exists. And of cource I will use it just as a quick fix until I remove that tag from GTM account.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot block a specific custom HTML programmatically. One reason is that it would be pointless - "custom HTML" means "arbitrary code executed in the context of your site", so the code could simply be put into another HTML tag and be run from there.

That you are not in control of the instance of GTM that runs in your site (which effectively means that you are not in control of your site) is not a use case that Google could cater for in any meaningful way (if you are in control of GTM then simply remove the tag).

If you mean that you want to disallow scripts of a certain origin then you might look into [Content Security Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)  (which will work no matter if the scripts runs from GTM or any other source). However CSPs are notoriously hard to implement (and while it is possible to [implement them from within GTM](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/meetup-161119162017/95/unmanaged-tags-data-protection-in-the-age-of-mindless-proliferation-13-638.jpg?cb=1480951174) this works only for limited testing, not for production use).