# Can't inject code on anonymous function inside a window.webpackJsonp object

Tags: javascript, code-injection, anonymous-function

Well, I'm trying to execute a function inside a minified Javascript in order to reproduce the behaviour of a context menu function.

I used Chrome dev tools with Event listeners breakpoints, as Rory suggested me on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895205/cant-determine-which-dom-element-has-the-context-menu-event-on-discordapp#comment105918105_59895205). And I discovered that the callback of the context menu event comes from this path:

```js
window.webpackJsonp[1][1][5754]
```

With this anonymous function after an indexer:

```js
5754: function(t, n, e) {
            "use strict";
// ...
}
```

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114600/3286975), somebody suggested to use this code:

```js
eval(doSomething.toString().replace(/}\s*$/, ' return id; $&');
```

I tried to inject this code:

```js
eval(window.webpackJsonp[1][1][5754].toString().replace(/}\s*$/, ' console.log(t); console.log(n); console.log(e); $&'));
```

I used `console.log` to know which objects are related to this arguments.

But this error prompted:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name.

So I don't know where to continue...

Answer (score 0):

Changing `eval(...)` to `eval('(' + ... + ')')` works for me.
The definition at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval says `eval` takes either expressions, e.g., `function () {}` or statements, e.g., `function foo () {}` so you've been bitten by an `eval` implementation bug.